# When I need to run io_service and why

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <utility>

namespace koicxx {

template <typename T>
class temp_storage : private boost::noncopyable
{
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer>                    shared_timer_t;
  typedef std::map<T, shared_timer_t>                                       timer_map_t;
  typedef std::pair<T, shared_timer_t>                                      timer_pair_t;
  typedef boost::function<void(const T&, const boost::system::error_code&)> callback_t;

public:
  temp_storage(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
    _io_service(io_service) {}

  bool add(const T& element, const boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type& timeout, callback_t callback = callback_t())
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(_sync);

    const std::pair<timer_map_t::iterator, bool>& res =
      _internal_storage.insert(
        timer_pair_t(
          element
          , shared_timer_t(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(_io_service, timeout))
        ));

    if (!res.second)
    {
        return false;
    }

    const timer_map_t::iterator& itr = res.first;

    if (callback)
    {
      itr->second->async_wait(
        boost::bind(
          callback
          , itr->first
          , boost::asio::placeholders::error
        ));
    }

    itr->second->async_wait(
      boost::bind(
        &temp_storage::remove_callback
        , this
        , itr->first
        , boost::asio::placeholders::error
      ));

    return true;
  }

  bool remove(const T& element)
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(_sync);

    const timer_map_t::iterator& itr = _internal_storage.find(element);
    if (itr == _internal_storage.end())
    {
        return false;
    }
    itr->second->cancel();

    _internal_storage.erase(itr);

    return true;
  }

  bool contains(const T& element)
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(_sync);

    return _internal_storage.find(element) != _internal_storage.end();
  }

  void clear()
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(_sync);

    for (timer_map_t::value_type& i : _internal_storage)
    {
        i.second->cancel();
    }

    _internal_storage.clear();
  }

private:
  void remove_callback(const T& element, const boost::system::error_code& e)
  {
    if (e == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        return;
    }
    remove(element);
  }

  boost::asio::io_service&  _io_service;
  timer_map_t               _internal_storage;
  boost::mutex              _sync;
};

} // namespace koicxx

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  koicxx::temp_storage<int> some_storage(io_service);
  some_storage.add(0, boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
  some_storage.add(1, boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
  some_storage.add(2, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

  while (true)
  {
    if (some_storage.contains(0))
    {
      std::cout << 0 << ' ';
    }
    if (some_storage.contains(1))
    {
      std::cout << 1 << ' ';
    }
    if (some_storage.contains(2))
    {
      std::cout << 2 << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}
```

When I need to run io_service and why? Could I make io_service member of the class? Is there smth wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never see your timers expire.

When calling `async_wait` what you are telling Asio is this: When the timer expires, I want you to schedule this callback for execution. Note that 'schedule' here does not mean 'execute immediately', but rather 'insert it into a queue of stuff that is ready for execution'. Said queue is part of `io_service`'s internals. Calling `run` on `io_service` will block until all pending work has been scheduled and executed.

The problem here is that run waits for both callbacks that have been scheduled (ie. those that are already ready for execution) and those that are still waiting to be scheduled (ie. those where you have called `async_wait` but where the timer has not expired yet). So just calling `run` from the main thread will simply block until all three of your timers have expired, which is probably not what you want.

You have two options now: You can either open a second thread to call `run`. This would work, but you would end up with two threads mostly doing nothing (the main thread, which is mainly sleeping in the loop, and the worker thread mainly sleeping on the `run` call).

A more lightweight approach is to call [`poll`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll.html) instead from the loop. Unlike `run`, `poll` only exeuctes callbacks that have been scheduled for execution already, but not those that are still waiting. If no such callbacks are available, `poll` returns immediately instead of blocking:

```
template <typename T>
class temp_storage : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    void do_poll() {
         io_service_.poll();
    }
[...]
};

int main()
{
   [...]
   while (true)
   {
       [...]
       some_storage.do_poll();
       boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! btw could I make io_service member of the class so the users of this class shouldn't know anything about all of its io_service, etc?

Comment: @FrozenHeart The `io_service` is needed for two things: By everyone who wants to _construct_ stuff that does asnychronous work (like sockets or timers), and then again by everyone who wants to execute work in form of asynchronous callbacks (that is, call stuff like `run` or `poll`). If you can encapsulate this properly, there is nothing that prevents you from hiding the `io_service` inside a class.